# How do you set up .vimrc

Tags: ubuntu, vim

How do you set up a .vimrc file on Ubuntu?

This is not helping: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file

1. Where do you create it?
2. Whats the format inside?

I know the stuff I want to put in it, just don't know how.

Comment: Just create file `~/.vimrc` and put settings you like there, and make yourself a favor - comment things inside.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Where:**

On UN*X systems your .vimrc belongs in your *home directory*. At a terminal, type:

```
cd $HOME
vim .vimrc
```

This will change to your home directory and open .vimrc using vim. In vim, add the commands that you know you want to put in, then type `:wq` to save the file.

Now open vim again. Once in vim you can just type: `:scriptnames` to print a list of scripts that have been sourced. The full path to your .vimrc should be in that list. As an additional check that your commands have been executed, you can:

- add an `echo "MY VIMRC LOADED"` command to the .vimrc, and when you run vim again, you should see *MY VIMRC LOADED* printed in the terminal. Remove the `echo` command once you've verified that your.vimrc is loading.
- set a variable in your .vimrc that you can `echo` once vim is loaded. In the .vimrc add a line like `let myvar="MY VIMRC LOADED"`. Then once you've opened vim type `echo myvar` in the command line. You should see your message.

**The Format:**

The format of your .vimrc is that it contains Ex commands: anything that you might type in the vim command-line following `:`, but in your .vimrc, leave off the `:`.

You've mentioned `:set ruler`: a .vimrc with only this command looks like:

```
set ruler
```

Search for *example vimrc* and look over the results. [This link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Example_vimrc) is a good starting point.

Comment: Oh so it just put in :set ruler normally, no brackets and stuff?

Comment: or simply enter `vim ~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 6):

.vimrc should be in your home directory. .vimrc is there to make more interactive according to your need. Here is an example of .vimrc

```
filetype indent on
set ai
set mouse=a
set incsearch
set confirm
set number
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest,full
```

Answer (score 0):

The ".vimrc"(vim resource configuration) file provides initialization settings that configure Vim every time it starts. This file can be found in `"$HOME/.vimrc"` for linux/OSX and `"$HOME/_vimrc"` for Window users. Inside Vim, type ":echo $HOME" to see the value of $HOME for your system

For example, we can do following settings in your `.vimrc` file.

```
    set hlsearch: Enable search highlighting
    set ignorecase: Ignore case when searching
    set incsearch: Incremental search that shows partial matches.
```

Answer (score 0):

Open vim `~/.vimrc` using `vim ~/.vimrc`, put this in it:

```
set paste
set nonumber
set hlsearch
```

Save the file and quit using `:wq`. Changes in this `.vimrc` will be used when reopening your Vim editor.